# Web-scraping with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a page whose classes are in this format `class="jss262 jss434 jss263"`

I tried to click on a box and insert a specific value but whether I use class, xpath or css selector, the element is not identified.

I believe I missed something but I'm not sure what it is. Is there a way to modify my code in order to access this element?

[image: Browser HTML inspector showing div with class="jss262 jss434 jss263" highlighted in yellow]

My code:

```
                            try:
                            button2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'jss262 jss434 jss263')))
                            button2.click()
                            button2.send_keys(att)
                            driver.implicitly_wait(5)
```

Comment: `(By.CLASS_NAME, 'jss262 jss434 jss263'.split())`

Comment: @thethiny thank you but no result

Comment: your text box is at `By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.jss270.jss435'` , is there any specific reason to go div before it?

Comment: @simpleApp this is what I was trying now actually but not working. I have used both .jss270.jss435 and jss262 jss434 jss263 with no success

Comment: if I create the html you have shown in question, then able to find by `By.CSS_SELECTOR,  '.jss270.jss435')` , and if i try to click on div, then i need to transverse to input text otherwise will get error like `Message: Element <div class="jss262 jss434 jss263"> is not reachable by keyboard`.  there are two way to recreate either url of the site or HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

`By.CLASS_NAME` only accepts one class, use `css_selector`:

```
button2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.jss262.jss434.jss263')))
```

Comment: thank you, unfortunately its not working

Comment: What are you getting?

Comment: I'm getting this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'presence_of_element_located'

Comment: I believe `ec` should be  `EC`. try it now.

Comment: I have used this while importing actually from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec